# Извлечение данных xpath с сайта

Tags: xpath, java, http

Добрый день!
Стоит задача извлечь данные с помощью xpath с сайта.

Единственное решение, которое я знаю, это использовать либу *Selenium web driver*(тихий, без загрузки самого сайта).В ней перейти на сайт , выполнить запрос , получить результат.

Но весь этот процесс избыточен и довольно медленный, хочется проще и быстрее.Что-то типо : отправить **HTTP** запрос, как-то увязать его с *xpath* и получить результат. Можете подсказать, как это сделать?

PS все делать строго на яве.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Возьмите какой-нибудь [Apache HttpClient](http://hc.apache.org/httpclient-3.x/), выкачайте контент, распарсите и стройте запросы, например [как тут](http://habrahabr.ru/post/128175/).

Comment: вы уверены, что это проще?)

Answer (score 0):

страницу скачать полюбому нужно. Но картинки и скрипты с нее качать скорее всего не нужно. А потом локально применить xpath. Либо поискать сервисы, которые сделают это для Вас - Вы им урл и xpath, они - кусок страницы.